# How to expire haproxy's stick table entry only after the closing of all sessions which used it

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy, high-availability, sticky-session

I'm currently using Haproxy 1.5, I have a backend with 2 servers. My app servers receive connection from two clients and I want both of them to be attributed to the same server. All connections have a url parameter X and sessions that should be attributed to the same server have the same url parameter X value. I use a stick table to save the server that a particular url parameter value uses so that future connections can be attributed to the same server.

I want to be able to add app servers as load increases. In order to instruct haproxy to move previous connections to the new app server I need to expire stick table entries when no session (of either client) is active in the server.

Can anyone help me with this?